# relation between the Wasserstein distance $W_1(p,q)$ to $L_1$ and $L_\infty$ distance

Tags: probability

Is the Wasserstein distance $W_1(p,q)$ with respect to $L_1$ between two discrete distributions $p$ and $q$ constitutes an upper or a lower bound on the $L_1$ or $L_\infty$ distance of the same distributions?

Comment: What do you mean by the $L_1$ or $L_{\infty}$-distance between measures? Are you assuming that $p$ and $q$ are discrete or something?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for this clarification, these are discrete probability vectors